# TakeList of a Dataset

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset

Check this out
[image]

I want to split the `Dataset` for graphical reasons, like creating a nice composition on a page, `TakeList` should do that.

Comment: Under "Properties and relations" in the documentation for `TakeList` it says how to implement `TakeList` in terms of `TakeDrop`, perhaps at least a serviceable workaround.

Answer (score 2):

```
With[{partition = TakeList[Range@Length@#, #2], d = #}, d /@ partition] &[dataset, {2, 4}]
```

[image]

Also:

```
Dataset /@ TakeList[Normal@dataset, {2, 4}]
```

> same result

or, a cleaner alternative suggested by C.E. in comments,

```
FoldPairList[TakeDrop, dataset, {2, 4}]
```

> same result

Comment: `Dataset /@ TakeList[Normal@dataset, {2, 4}]` should be by default I think